# How to pick what unit to display a value in?

Tags: algorithm, theory, heuristics, units-of-measurement

I have a value and I known that it's units is

> meters<sup>mn/md</sup> * kg<sup>kn/kd</sup> * s<sup>sn/sd</sup> * K<sup>Kn/Kd</sup> * A<sup>An/Ad</sup>

Note: the exponents are rational, units of m<sup>0.5</sup> are valid

The question is how to pick how to break down the units into something more compact

for instance if

```
md=kd=sd=Kd=Ad=1
mn=Kn=An=0
kn=1
sn=-1
```

I can use N/m

I suspect that this is some subset of a discrete optimization problem.

Comment: You probably meant meters^(mn-md) * kg^(kn-kd) * s^(sn-sd) * K^(Kn-Kd) * A^(An-Ad)

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Define the complexity as the total number of symbols: A unit to the power of 1 has complexity 1, any other integer power is 2, a fractional power is 3. Try several examples and see how it feels. Maybe you have to use other numbers than 1, 2, 3 for complexities.

Try optimization using a greedy algorithm: on each iteration, factor out the composite unit (possibly to a fractional or negative power) that simplifies as much as possible (makes the target function as small as possible). I have a hunch that greed will work because the units are designed so that if the product / ratio of two units is simpler than each of them, it will be a unit of its own.